# Multi parent child class (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, controller

I have a `Planning`class in my app. That class can belong to three different classes (`System`, `Subsystem` OR  `Subsubsystem`) depending on the users will. To be more clear: the user must be able to create a `Planning` from any one of those 3 classes.

I'm having no trouble with the models, but in my `plannings_controller#new`, i don't know what to do.

This is what the `new` method would look like if the mother-class were a system:

```
@system = System.find(params[:system_id])
@planning = @system.plannings.build

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @planning }
end
```

end

Can anyone tell me a way of managing the plannings controller so it would know which class is the mother-class?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using STI so `System`, `Subsystem` and `Subsubsystem` map to the same DB table? In that case, you should have a parent model `GenericSystem` and no need to specify the exact model because the systems would be polymorphic to `#plannings`.

Comment: searched now for STI and it seems to be a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If by

> multi parent child class

you are referring to multiple inheritance, you know there is no such thing in Ruby.

Comment: i'm not referring to inheritance, i'm referring to relations. mother class != superclass

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  (polymorphic)

`class Planning < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plannable, :polymorphic => true
end`

class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :planning, :as => 'plannable' 
end

class Subsystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :planning, :as => 'plannable' 
end

Comment: nice! but how do I use this stuff in my plannings_controller#new method? wouldnt it be nice to use STI? thank you

Comment: you can use sti as well if you prefer.. if the system classes are all simillar